# Error: "NameError: name 'pwn' is not defined"

Tags: python

After using the following command to download pwn tools

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pwntools
```

I created a python file called exp.py and in the top of the file I import the pwn tools like this

```
import pwn
```

I also used this method

```
from pwn import *
```

but am running the program and am getting the following msg

```
File "exp.py", line 5, in <module>
    pwn.context.log_level = 'critical'
NameError: name 'pwn' is not defined
```

Comment: What are you running the `.py` script with ?

Comment: running it like this: python3 exp.py

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - maybe you run wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

After looking on the code the problem was that i was writing the function from pwn like this

```
pwn.function()
```

So i was getting the error of  pwn.context.log_level = 'critical', if i remvoed the pwn and keep it like this context.log_level = 'critical' the error did not appear